# Fetch phpmyadmin data from dropdown menu on the same page

Tags: php

You may have seen some website while filling up the registration form you have to select country from drop down list and another drop down field automatically send the states or cities of the country by fetching from database.

The same way I have data in myphpmyadmin db. In one table I have department names and another table I have employee name. When the user select the department from dropdown list, the another drop down list should show the employee names.

Please let me know how to to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

Every department will have a unique id, for example IT department have an ID of 14. Similarly every employee has its unique id and also the department ID. For example Jhone Doe is in IT department then his department ID will be 14.

Your employee table will have a department ID field where you will be placing department ID for each employee.

When department drop down is selected, the value of the selected department (ID) will be sent to the query and all employee for that department will be selected. The query will be like as below(Say IT department is selected whose ID is 14):

```
select * from employees where department_id = 14;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: but how the all employee for that department will appear on the same page. When we select the department ID and by pressing GO we will go to the next page. I want the value appear on the same page. I think we need ajex or jquery.

Comment: Yes, for this you will need JQuery ajax ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ). After making the call, create the drop down of the employee in the php and echo it there in php file. Then using JQuery place that returned drop down list in your html below the drop down list of departments

Comment: hi can u tell me your skype or any messanger id. Just for making the connection. Can u a tell me the code.

Comment: please ask google, and google will provide you good posts links where you will be able to learn jquery ajax easily